# Getting ASP Table from code behind does not return dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my code asp.net page, I have an ASP table, which has a table header.  In the codebehind, I generate all of the table rows.  I then have a button that I want to export the data, but when I retrieve the ASP Table, it only has the table header and not the dynamically created table rows.  Here is what I have

```
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CssClass="display table table-hover">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="Table1HeaderRow"
            BackColor="LightBlue"
            runat="server" >
            <asp:TableHeaderCell
                Scope="Column" Visible="true"
                Text="ID" ID="columnID" />
            <asp:TableHeaderCell
                Scope="Column" Visible="true"
                Text="Name" ID="columnName" />
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

I then build by data rows like this:

```
Dim TR As New TableRow
Dim id_cell As New TableCell
Dim title_cell As New TableCell

id_cell.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(item.ID))
title_cell.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(item.name))

TR.Cells.Add(id_cell)
TR.Cells.Add(title_cell)

Me.Table1.Rows.Add(TR)
```

I also have a button on the page, but when I retrieve the Table, it just has the header rows, and  not the dynamic rows:

```
  Dim table As Table = Me.Table1
  Dim count as integer = table.rows.count 'this just has one
```

How do I get then entire table?  As a side note, I have to use the Table control, as opposed to gridview or repeater, for other reasons.

Comment: You didn't show exactly how you're exporting it, but as a general rule you would have to re-add all the dynamic data again before exporting...it doesn't persist between postbacks. But why not use a databound gridview to display your table? They were invented for just this kind of situation

Comment: well, the export is not an issue.  It exports what it gets from Me.Table1, but the issue is that Me.Table1 only has the header row, not the dynamic data.  I can see this with a break point.  So, the post back loses all of the dynamic data?

Comment: Yes. HTTP applications are inherently stateless. Asp.net webforms works round this by holding information in the ViewState, but this only works for items declared explicitly in the aspx page e.g. by creating `<asp:...` markup. For anything else, you have to re-run it on every postback. That's why I suggest to use a gridview to make this easier - databinding helps with preserving state

Comment: OK, thats what I thought.  I'll have to try and rework this to use a repeater or gridview. thanks